# Linux Mint not detecting microSD card

Tags: drivers, sd-card

I have a microSD card in my Android device and I would like to plug it into my computer to change the music and collected photos.

However, I'm not able to do this. The OS does not seem to even notice that I have a microSD card plugged in (not even when I plug-in my Huawei Android with it as well).

I have a dual boot of Windows and Linux Mint, with 2 auto-mounted partitions, but I do not think this is the problem.

Could it be a driver problem?

---

I also tried the command `lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 SDXC`, however it prints no output at all in the console. However, I used kdepaste and posted the results of lspci -vnn [here](http://pastebin.kde.org/pk4mi3d47).

---

Additional information:

1. What type of device is this?

   - The problem is occurring in a laptop: CLEVO W150ER
2. Is it a microSD card or an SSD card?

   - This is the microSD card that i use on my cellphone. It has an adapter, which is a bigger card in which the smaller one fits, [just like in this image](http://700inaweek123.co.uk/images/Kingston_2GB_Micro_SD_Card_with_AdapteraDetail.jpg)
3. Are you attempting to tether the device to your PC? If so what is the nature of the connection? USB? Bluetooth?

   - My laptop has an entrance for SD cards. My SDcard worked before on Windows, so I know it should now as well.
4. Are you attempting to just mount and SSD card?

   - Not sure what you mean by this :S

Comment: Could you pls post the output of lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 SDXC       Ty

Comment: In order to assist you we're going to need a few additional pieces of information. (1) What type of device is this? - be specific! (2) Is it a microSD card or an SSD card? (3) Are you attempting to tether the device to your PC? If so what is the nature of the connection? USB? Bluetooth? (4) Are you attempting to just mount and SSD card?

Comment: Ok guys, I added more information to the post. Hope it is all you need :S

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Arch Linux I installed the `opensc` package from the official repository; it solved all my microSD card problems.

Comment: [OpenSC](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki) is for handling "smart cards" (used for authentication purposes) and has nothing at all to do with microSD detection or operation. The improvements you saw were likely a coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint, then installed `opensc` and now it works. From the `/var/log/syslog` it seems to be a problem with the cdc driver trying to use the device.